How do I disable local authentication in Azure API Management
How do I remove the option to sign in with local user accounts in the Azure API Management Developer portal? That is not show the choice/username - password form on the login page, and in the current case only show the Azure EntraID login button.
Is the only way to delete the local auth form block on the login page, or can this be configured?

Please try to delete 'Username and password' in APIM->Developer Portal->Identities

Is your issue resolved ?Please provide more details about the issue.

As mentioned by @MarkusMeyer yes you need to delete the UserName and Password identity provider in Identities section.

And also publish your portal in Developer portal => Portal overview

Thanks @Markus Meyer for the comment.
As mentioned by Markus and as per this MSDoc, you need to delete the Identity provider of Username and Password.


That is not show the choice/username - password form on the login page, and in the current case only show the Azure EntraID login button.

For this you need to add the Azure AD Identity provider.


Is the only way to delete the local auth form block on the login page

If you delete the Username and password, it will not allow you to login. If you want to completely avoid the block delete both identity provider and form in login page.
